# splitting file based on 5000 bytes

Tags: java

I have split the file based on the below code,

```
    int sizeOfFiles = 1024 * 3;// 1MB
    byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeOfFiles];

   // String fileName = f.getName();

    //try-with-resources to ensure closing stream
    try (ByteArrayInputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(f);) {

        int bytesAmount = 0;
        int i=0;
        while ((bytesAmount = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {

            String result="";
            for (byte b : buffer) {
                result+=(char)b;
            }

            System.out.println(result);

           System.out.print("--------------------------------------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

But when I copy the first 3072 bytes in the buffer and paste it in the notepad++, I was getting to show that the same data is more than 3072 bytes.
Can you please help me with this issue?

Note: I am using windows server, eclipse and file or string is in the format UTF-8 charset.

Comment: *"when I copy the first 3072 bytes in the buffer and paste it in the notepad++"* how did you do this part?

Comment: I have printed the buffer result with the line divider, after the first buffer, it will draw a line. I have taken the data between the lines and pasted in the notepadd++

Comment: there's no line divider in your current code (unless you mean `\n`), can you please show us a version with this line divider which gives the same problem?

Comment: please have a check now, I have included the line in the code. I have taken the data between lines and pasted in the notepad++

Comment: Hi maran, I have thought the same but when my data is copied into notepad, I have got more than that bytes

Comment: more than 3072 bytes - Exactly how many bytes were there?

Comment: Are you certain that both the terminal and clipboard also support utf-8 (and that it's enabled)?

Comment: Hi, I am sure that both supports UTF-8 and it is enabled in both , it is howing exactly 3188 bytes and I have taken the HTML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that there is a bug in this line:

```
for (byte b : buffer) {
```

You are assuming that all of the byte positions in `buffer` contain data.  But what if the `read` call returned fewer than `sizeOfFiles` bytes?

The second problem is that this line is liable to mangle the data.

```
result += (char) b;
```

You are taking each byte of input and casting it to a character.  But if the input file is binary, those bytes don't represent characters.  Alternatively, if the input is text, then a real character in the input may be encoded as 2 or more bytes, for example.  Either way, when you cast from a `byte` to `char` you are not getting proper Unicode code units to append to the string

(The only cases where what you are doing would "work" are is the input file is ASCII or LATIN-1 encoded text.)

This mangling may well be increasing the number of bytes relative to the input stream, especially if you are outputting in UTF-8.  Any input byte in the range 128 to 255 will turn into 2 bytes when cast to a `char` and then encoded in UTF-8.

Finally, when you use `println` to output the string you are adding an extra line separator after each buffer-full of data.

Comment: And as a char as multibyte sequence may be split by the buffered read, one may have half a char at the beginning or end.